# Unable to Integrate OneSignal Android SDK on new Gradle Structure Android Studio Bumblebee

Tags: android, android-studio, onesignal, android-studio-bumblebee

As Android Studio is rolling out the useless updates they have changed the gradle structure to significantly complex.

I am trying to integrate OneSignal SDK in my Android App and following their documentation
https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/mobile-sdk-setup

However their documentation is decades old and is not compatible with new gradle structure, can someone please help me to integrate this simple plug in?

Comment: whats the specify error your are getting?

Comment: @AtiarTalukdar : I do not know where exactly to put the dependency and classpath dependency in the new structure, tried all possible cases but was unable to get it integrated.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this...

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    ..........
    id 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin' version '[0.14.0, 0.99.99]' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```